# How to filter a listview by DateTime

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a sensor readings monitoring app and I need to get the records of the readings. I have written the records in list view by order of the time it was sent by the database. I need to be able to search the date and get all the readings that was received along that day.
This is where I get my data from:
http://mushroomdroid.online/dbscript-1.php

and this how I displayed the data using listview:

```
class RecordsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RecordsPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RecordsPage> createState() => _RecordsPageState();
}


class _RecordsPageState extends State<RecordsPage> {
  final String url = "http://mushroomdroid.online/dbscript-1.php";
  List<Readings> AllData = [];
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadData();
  }

  loadData() async {
    var response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String responseBody = response.body;
      var jsonBody = json.decode(responseBody);
      for (var data in jsonBody) {
        AllData.add(new Readings(
            int.parse(data['id']),
            double.parse(data['temperature']),
            double.parse(data['humidity']),
            data['FanStatus'],
            data['MistStatus'],
            DateTime.parse(data['Time'])));
      }
      setState(() {});
      AllData.forEach((someData) => print("FanStatus: ${someData.FanStatus}"));
    } else {
      print('Something went wrong');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var container;

    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: AllData.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return new Container(
            child: new Card(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/records.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                )),
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: new Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      'READINGS ON: ${AllData[index].Time}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      'TEMPERATURE: ${AllData[index].temperature}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      'HUMIDITY: ${AllData[index].humidity}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      'FAN STATUS: ${AllData[index].FanStatus}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                    new Text(
                      'MIST STATUS: ${AllData[index].FanStatus}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Please help me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In `loadData()` method `for (var data in jsonBody)`, you can add some condition to check datetime valid before execute `AllData.add`.

**Example**: i write a filter extension that allow i get new list filtered by my condition (filter by name or time).

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

final timeFm = DateFormat.yMd();

void main() {
  var history = <LogHistory>[
    LogHistory("A", DateTime(1990, 1, 1).millisecondsSinceEpoch),
    LogHistory("A", DateTime(2020, 1, 1).millisecondsSinceEpoch),
    LogHistory("B", DateTime(2020, 1, 1).millisecondsSinceEpoch),
  ];
    
  print('originalObjects: $history');

  print('---------------------------------------');
  print('filtered by name: A');
  print('result: ${history.filterBy(name: "A")}');
  
  print('---------------------------------------');
  print('filtered by time: 1/1/2000');
  print('result: ${history.filterBy(time: DateTime(2000, 1, 1).millisecondsSinceEpoch)}');
  
  print('---------------------------------------');
  print('filtered by time: 1/1/2020');
  print('result: ${history.filterBy(time: DateTime(2020, 1, 1).millisecondsSinceEpoch)}');
  
  print('---------------------------------------');
  print('filtered by both name & time: B + 1/1/2020');
  print('result: ${history.filterBy(name: "B", time: DateTime(2020, 1, 1).millisecondsSinceEpoch)}');
}

class LogHistory {
  String name;
  int timeInMiliseconds;
  LogHistory(this.name, this.timeInMiliseconds);
  
  DateTime get time => DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timeInMiliseconds);
  
  @override
  String toString() => "{name: $name, time: ${timeFm.format(time)}}";
}

extension LFilter on List<LogHistory> {
  List<LogHistory> filterBy({String? name, int? time}){
    final nameFilter = name ?? "";
    final timeFilter = time != null ? DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(time) : null;
    List<LogHistory> ret = [];
    for (var object in this) {
      var passFilter = true;

      if(nameFilter.isNotEmpty && object.name != nameFilter){
        passFilter = false;
      }

      if(timeFilter != null && object.time != timeFilter){
        passFilter = false;
      }

      if(passFilter) ret.add(object);
    }
    return ret;
  }
}
```

Result:

```
originalObjects: [{name: A, time: 1/1/1990}, {name: A, time: 1/1/2020}, {name: B, time: 1/1/2020}]
---------------------------------------
filtered by name: A
result: [{name: A, time: 1/1/1990}, {name: A, time: 1/1/2020}]
---------------------------------------
filtered by time: 1/1/2000
result: []
---------------------------------------
filtered by time: 1/1/2020
result: [{name: A, time: 1/1/2020}, {name: B, time: 1/1/2020}]
---------------------------------------
filtered by both name & time: B + 1/1/2020
result: [{name: B, time: 1/1/2020}]
```

**Update**: update example with your json

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

final timeFm = DateFormat.yMd();

final json = [
  {
    "id": "1416",
    "temperature": "32.65",
    "humidity": "379.4",
    "FanStatus": "ON",
    "MistStatus": "OFF",
    "Time": "2022-05-11 04:30:55"
  },
  {
    "id": "1415",
    "temperature": "32.47",
    "humidity": "70.61",
    "FanStatus": "ON",
    "MistStatus": "ON \r\n",
    "Time": "2022-05-11 04:20:54"
  },
  {
    "id": "1352",
    "temperature": "29.02",
    "humidity": "77.61",
    "FanStatus": "ON",
    "MistStatus": "ON \r\n",
    "Time": "2022-05-10 16:48:57"
  },
  {
    "id": "1351",
    "temperature": "28.99",
    "humidity": "383.65",
    "FanStatus": "OFF",
    "MistStatus": "OFF",
    "Time": "2022-05-10 16:38:57"
  },
  {
    "id": "34",
    "temperature": "33.71",
    "humidity": "68.53",
    "FanStatus": "ON",
    "MistStatus": "ON",
    "Time": "2021-06-01 03:31:47"
  },
  {
    "id": "33",
    "temperature": "33.7",
    "humidity": "68.61",
    "FanStatus": "ON",
    "MistStatus": "ON",
    "Time": "2021-05-09 03:31:47"
  },
];

void main() {
  var history = json.map(LogHistory.fromJson).toList();

  print('total results from api: ${history.length}');

  print('---------------------------------------');
  print('filter by year: 2021');
  print('found: ${history.filterByTime(year: 2021).length}');

  print('---------------------------------------');
  print('filter by month: 5');
  print('found: ${history.filterByTime(month: 5).length}');

  print('---------------------------------------');
  print('filter by day: 10');
  print('found: ${history.filterByTime(day: 10).length}');
  
  print('---------------------------------------');
  print('filter by both year and month: 2021-06');
  print('found: ${history.filterByTime(year: 2021, month: 6).length}');
}

class LogHistory {
  int id;
  String timeRaw;

  LogHistory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data)
      : id = int.parse(data['id']),
        timeRaw = data['Time'];

  DateTime get time => DateTime.parse(timeRaw);

  @override
  String toString() => "{id: $id, time: ${timeFm.format(time)}}";
}

extension LFilter on List<LogHistory> {
  List<LogHistory> filterByTime({int? year, int? month, int? day}) {
    List<LogHistory> ret = [];
    for (var object in this) {
      var passFilter = true;

      if (year != null && object.time.year != year) {
        passFilter = false;
      }
      if (month != null && object.time.month != month) {
        passFilter = false;
      }
      if (day != null && object.time.day != day) {
        passFilter = false;
      }

      if (passFilter) ret.add(object);
    }
    return ret;
  }
}
```

Result:

```
total results from api: 6
---------------------------------------
filter by year: 2021
found: 2
---------------------------------------
filter by month: 5
found: 5
---------------------------------------
filter by day: 10
found: 2
---------------------------------------
filter by both year and month: 2021-06
found: 1
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! However, this is not the answer I am looking for... If ever I got it wrong. My goal is to have a search bar and I can enter the Date and the search results will give me the date and all the readings in that date. My code gives an error The method 'contains' isn't defined for the type 'int'. I want to be able to make it so it can accept the DateTime variable type or other variable types. How can I do that?

Comment: @MarkAllenMolina just change abit logic bro, i ll rewrite answer later

Comment: @MarkAllenMolina check answer **Update**